# When will the "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object " runtime error occurs?

Tags: asp.net

I am using the Frame work 4 of ASP.Net and i got recently the runtime error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object " in my Production Website.

Can i know when this error will occur, but in my local system the error did not occurred.

What would be the resolution and i want to know how this error will occurred?

Comment: Did you check the Application Event Log for details? There's really not much anybody can help you with this little information.

Comment: please provide more details. Where the error appears? When? Stack trace?

Comment: I have a page and in the page i will be creating the PDF's where i will provide the start value and end value. based on the values provided the PDF's will be generated. so if i pass the values as 1 to 1000 then i am getting this error. Actually this error i am getting from the Production but i am not able to get this error in my local system. If any more information needed let me know so that i can provide much more information. Under the Stack Trace i am getting as System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded()

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error during postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos)

Answer (score 0):

In the client web.config, the maximum length of the ViewState is set to 8K using following attribute maxPageStateFieldLength=“8192“.

then the above error will be gone.