# The URL encoded form data is invalid or Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

## Background

I have inherited an ASP.NET web application project that has been passed on for the last 6-7 years. The site is running on .NET 2.0 and IIS 7.5 on my development machine and IIS 6.0 on the production server. A further snag to this is that I can not change or refactor the page into smaller fragments. The usual office politics apply, client will not pay for it, no time to do it, resources stretched as is..

## Problem

There is one page that has an ASP:Table server control that literally generates hundreds on textboxes.

I have noticed that when it reaches a certain amount of rows that an IIS exception is thrown:

**Local Development Machine (IIS 7.5, .NET 2.0)**

> HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request
>
> ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL.
>   ..ErrorPage.aspx?ErrorMsg=The+URL-encoded+form+data+is+not+valid.

**Production (IIS 6.0, .NET 2.0)**

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

I have searched around for a couple of hours and I have come across a couple of threads e.g. [Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. when i select dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697194/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-when-i-select-dro)

I have tried inserting the following AppSettings (shown below) in my `Web.config` and cannot get this issue resolved:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2000" />
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this issue or get the above settings to take affect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be (and it's hard to know without seeing the page) that your huge number of checkboxes are generating an equally huge viewstate - this could be exceeded the max request length or similar when you post back, or the form is simply truncated. Is the ViewState large?

Comment: Since your question states that you are generating hundreds of controls per page... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx

Comment: @dash I really can't post the code. Mainly because it's monolithic and enormous. The viewstate is ~ 20,000 characters in length.

Comment: @Jupaol Yes I agree, this is not my code or design. To make things even more frustrating I can not touch the code to refactor etc until we get a purchase order/change request. That's why I'm asking the community for help at 23:22 at night :)

Comment: I've heard stories about certain browsers not posting the entirety of large form fields (which, of course, includes ViewState). Do you need ViewState on the page [chances are you do] because if you don't then you could try turning it off.

Comment: Yeah that sucks... One question are you using query string?

Comment: @dash - Yep ViewState is there to stay I'm afraid.

Comment: @Jupaol - No, there's no use of the QueryString.