# grouping and flatening 1:M:M:1 related data in Entity Framework Core/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In a small ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework and LINQ I want to achieve a method which queries to which rooms a person needs access to. The desired result for a single person looks like that

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "First1",
  "lastname": "Last1",
  "rooms": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test room 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test room 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test room 3"
      }
    ]
}
```

Now the rooms are not directly assigned to a person but a person has multiple tasks (each task can have only one person), each task requieres access to multiple rooms (so there is a M:N between tasks and rooms). And the rooms table stores the room id and name.

So I have 4 tables:

1. Person (id, firstname, lastname)
2. Task (id, personId, name)
3. TaskRoom (id, roomId, taskId)
4. Room (id, name) -> the data that should be displayed

The connections between the tables are:

- Person 1:M Task
- Task 1:M TaskRoom
- TaskRoom N:1 Room

My current methods looks like that

```
[HttpGet("RoomAccess/{personId:int}")]
public IActionResult RoomAccess(int personId)
{
    _logger.LogDebug(string.Format("{0}.RoomAccess(person id: {1})", GetType().Name, personId));

    var result = _dbContext.Person
        .Include(p => p.Task).ThenInclude(t => t.TaskRoom).ThenInclude(tr => tr.Room)
        .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
        .Select(person => new
        {
            person.Id,
            person.Firstname,
            person.Lastname,

            // how to do that line?
            rooms = person.Task.Select(ta => ta.TaskRoom.Select(tr => new {id = tr.Room.Id, name = tr.Room.Name} ) )
        }
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();

    if (result == null) 
    {
        return NotFound(string.Format("person id: {0}", personId));
    }

    return Ok(result);
}
```

And the result so far:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "First1",
  "lastname": "Last1",
  "rooms": [
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test room 1"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test room 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test room 3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test room 3"
      }
    ],
    []
  ]
}
```

Here are also empty brackets `[]` at the end for a task to which no room is assigned (so far).
And test room 3 occurs multiple times since two different tasks require access to this room.

How do I get a grouped list of related rooms holding only the id and name of the room (like in the example for the desired result)

Any help is welcome.

---

Now there is an open issue on [EF Core Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7419)

---

### Answer

Well the working code is:

```
[HttpGet("RoomAccess/{personId:int}")]
        public IActionResult RoomAccess(int personId)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug(string.Format("{0}.RoomAccess(person id: {1})", GetType().Name, personId));

            var result = _dbContext.Person
                .Include(p => p.Task).ThenInclude(t => t.TaskRoom).ThenInclude(tr => tr.Room)
                .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
                .ToList()
                .Select(person => new
                    {
                        person.Id,
                        person.Firstname,
                        person.Lastname,

                        rooms = person.Task.SelectMany(ta => ta.TaskRoom.Select(
                            tr => new { id = tr.Room.Id, name = tr.Room.Name })
                        )
                        .Distinct()
                        .OrderBy(adt => adt.name)
                    }
                )
                .FirstOrDefault();


            if (result == null) 
            {
                return NotFound(string.Format("person id: {0}", personId));
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

In addition to the answer of Nkosi it is important to use Include() and ThenInclude() as well as .ToList() after the Where().

Comment: Use the `SelectMany` extension. `rooms = person.Task.SelectMany(ta => ta.TaskRoom.Select(tr => new {id = tr.Room.Id, name = tr.Room.Name} ) )` Not sure how it will get transposed in EF though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SelectMany` extension to flatten the lists.

```
//...
rooms = person.Task
    .SelectMany(ta => ta.TaskRoom.Select(tr => new {id = tr.Room.Id, name = tr.Room.Name}))
    .Distinct()
//...
```

Not sure how it will get transposed in EF though and any performance impact.

Note the use of `Distinct` to remove any duplicates.

Comment: <code>System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.</code>

Comment: @monty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697194/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-when-i-select-dro

Comment: The same exception with <code>Distinct()</code>. It also seems to be a different exception than the linked one since the Stacktrace looks different: <code>System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  Source=System.Linq.Expressions
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression2.GetArgument(Int32 index)</code>

Comment: @monty I guess just another EF Core bug :(

Comment: @Nkosi Well, you was right from the beginning on. Just missed the Include() and ThenInclude() as well as the important ToList(). Still don't get why the .ToList() is that important but now it works. Thx