# 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error during postback after increasing MaxHttpCollectionKeys to 2500000

Tags: asp.net

I am using view state and many contols in gridview on a page.

I have also increased maxhttpcollection keys but still ther is error on server.

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: just binding a grid with datasource and two textboxes in item templates for each record.
there is approx 400 records in datasource.

Comment: try to do iisreset. IF you are using cassini, stop it and run application again...

Comment: i have done , it is working at local server as well but problem on production server.

Answer (score 0):

You find the answer here: ['Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error during postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos)

Add the following to your app settings in your web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
</appSettings>
```