# Adding Max Http Collection Keys could not resolved my issue

Tags: asp.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

NOTE: I am using ASP.NET 1.1 with visual studio 2003.

I have repeater control with 250 records (100 per page). I was getting this error
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object". After googling i increase the collection keys by putting this code into the web.config

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="9999" />
```

But it did not resolve my problem. Could any one have idea what to do now?

Comment: Possible post your `StackTrace` here.

Comment: You'll want to provide more details about the exception you're getting, like some of the stacktrace. For instance, are you getting the same stacktrace as in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos

Comment: @MelissaAvery-Weir yes it is

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/8955848/374383?