# Undo stops working in Visual Studio 2015 - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When editing Razor views in Visual Studio 2015 the undo function stops working. I noticed that it seems to when I type `@if` and press `tab`. Then I sometimes get the a pop up with the error message `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object` and then what appears is something like this, instead of the usual if-statement:

```
                @if (true)
    {
        /.../
    }
```

I have already tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2661403) solution but it didn't work. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I have already tried that and it made no difference unfortunately. Also the symptoms are different, I never get the yellow page of death, just a pop up and broken undo-feature. And in my case it happens when I edit, not when running the application.