# On button click control not going to Sub

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have  Button with `id = btnUploadxml` , as shown;

```
<td>
   <div id="divUpload" runat="server">
      <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
           style="font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, MS Sans Serif;font-size: 9pt; font-weight:bolder;" 
           BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" Height="50px" 
           CssClass="ceva-form-btn btn-dialog" Width="458px" />              
      <asp:Button  Text="Import File" runat="server" ID="btnUploadxml"   />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
</td>
```

And after clicking on the button, control should go to

```
 Public Sub btnUploadxml_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUploadxml.Click

    If Not FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        ErImport.Text = "ErImport, File required"
        ErImport.Visible = "True"
        'UIValidator.AddErrorSummary("", "Select file to import", "File required")
```

on the click control should go to My `btnUploadxml_Click` sub, but some how its giving me error

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.".

Please advice !!

Comment: Do you have a lot of form fields? Maybe you need to [increase the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos).

Comment: you are right, after increase the limit its work fine for me.. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

try to put inside your web.config file this code:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
</appSettings>
```

You will override the default value that is 1000. Try 2001 or bigger value.
The definition of this value is this:

```
 aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys

Limits the maximum number of items that can be present in any of the client-   provided dictionaries of the HttpRequest object.
```