# How to return to pipeline root after branch executing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

In the OWIN pipeline, i use a branch to configure a custom authentication middleware. How to return to pipeline root after branch executing?

```
app.Use<AuthenticationMiddleware1>();
app.Map("/branch", (application) => {
    application.Use<AuthenticationMiddleware2>();
});
app.UseWebApi(new HttpConfiguration());
```

When i request `http://server/branch` then web api is not configured and return 404

I tried to write a `MapAndContinueMiddleware`:

```
public class MapAndContinueMiddleware:OwinMiddleware
{
    public MapAndContinueMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, MapOptions options) : base(next)
    {
        this.Options = options;
    }

    public MapOptions Options { get; }


    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if(context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(this.Options.PathMatch))
        {
            await this.Options.Branch(context).ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
            {
                this.Next.Invoke(context);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            await this.Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

with this extension :

```
public static IAppBuilder MapAndContinue(this IAppBuilder app, string pathMatch, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration)
{
    // create branch and assign to options
    IAppBuilder branch = app.New();
    configuration(branch);

    MapOptions options = new MapOptions {
        PathMatch = new PathString(pathMatch),
        Branch = (Func<IOwinContext, Task>)branch.Build(typeof(Func<IOwinContext, Task>))
    };
    return MapAndContinue(app, options);
}

public static IAppBuilder MapAndContinue(this IAppBuilder app, MapOptions options)
{
    return app.Use<MapAndContinueMiddleware>(options);
}
```

But this has a strange behaviour : a web api request run the branch twice and doesn't return to client...!?

Comment: Did you base you code on the original `MapMiddleware`. I'm reviewing the source and it looks similar

Comment: Also what version are you using as the provided code in your example has syntax errors for `MapOptions.Branch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried continuing the pipeline as configured after the branch

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
app.Use<AuthenticationMiddleware1>();
app.Map("/branch", (application) => {
    application.Use<AuthenticationMiddleware2>();
    application.UseWebApi(config);
});
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

That way after the branch it will still be able to use the Web API

Reviewing the [Original `MapExtension` Source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin/Mapping/MapExtensions.cs#L17) it would seem that the order of when you add the middleware to the pipeline is important

Review the following refactor to use your custom map middleware

```
using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;

//...

public static class BranchAndMergeExtensions {

    public static IAppBuilder MapAndContinue(this IAppBuilder app, string pathMatch, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration) {
        return MapAndContinue(app, new PathString(pathMatch), configuration);
    }

    public static IAppBuilder MapAndContinue(this IAppBuilder app, PathString pathMatch, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration) {
        if (app == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
        }
        if (configuration == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("configuration");
        }
        if (pathMatch.HasValue && pathMatch.Value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Path must not end with slash '/'", "pathMatch");
        }

        // put middleware in pipeline before creating branch
        var options = new MapOptions { PathMatch = pathMatch };
        var result = app.Use<MapAndContinueMiddleware>(options);

        // create branch and assign to options
        IAppBuilder branch = app.New();
        configuration(branch);
        options.Branch = (AppFunc)branch.Build(typeof(AppFunc));

        return result;
    }
}
```

The [original `MapMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin/Mapping/MapMiddleware.cs#L51) also needed to be refactored to stop it from short-circuiting the pipeline by letting the root pipeline to be invoked after the branch.

```
public class MapAndContinueMiddleware : OwinMiddleware {
    private readonly MapOptions options;

    public MapAndContinueMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, MapOptions options)
        : base(next) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {
        PathString path = context.Request.Path;
        PathString remainingPath;
        if (path.StartsWithSegments(options.PathMatch, out remainingPath)) {
            // Update the path
            PathString pathBase = context.Request.PathBase;
            context.Request.PathBase = pathBase + options.PathMatch;
            context.Request.Path = remainingPath;

            //call branch delegate
            await this.options.Branch(context.Environment);

            context.Request.PathBase = pathBase;
            context.Request.Path = path;
        }
        // call next delegate
        await this.Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Which finally results in your original setup example becoming

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
app.Use<AuthenticationMiddleware1>();
app.MapAndContinue("/branch", (application) => {
    application.Use<AuthenticationMiddleware2>();
});
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Comment: yes of course but the configuration is more complicated than this exemple and i wish leave the code in separate files `Startup.Authenitication` and `Startup.WebApi`

Comment: @Troopers If it is more complicated then I suggest showing a more complicated example that is more closely align with your actual problem. Current suggestions will be made based on the currently provided examples.

Comment: I cannot display all my code here, but in the idea replace app.UseWebApi with several middlewares.

Comment: I understand not being able to show all your code, but a [mcve] is required. I could easily say wrap those other middleware in an extension method and make the same call in the branch. You see what I mean?

Comment: Ok. but i want also understand why my MapAndContinueMiddleware doesn't work!

Comment: Because it is creating its own path/branch and you are also mixing async and continuewith

Comment: I used the branch as `Func<IOwinContext, Task>` instead of  `Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>` to pass the owin context and not only the environment. Of course i created a new MapOptions class with this. I'm not sure that this change can be the origine of my problem. I just tried your code and it fails with _Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object_ on `await this.Next.Invoke(context);` after the branch executing

Comment: @Troopers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos

Comment: @Troopers also remember that `IOwinContext` - `This wraps OWIN environment dictionary and provides strongly typed accessors`. so makes not much of a difference if you use either