# How to fix 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error in .Net Azure Function App?

Tags: .net, web-config, azure-functions

I have a .NET Azure Function executed by Logic Apps triggered by an SQL connector "When an item is created V2". The function gathers data from multiple APIs and inserts the data into a SQL DB. The function works good for singular records, however, when a batch of records is inserted into the SQL table triggering the function, then the function breaks with the following error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

According to multiple threads on the Stack Overflow (i.e. ['Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error during postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos) ), to resolve the problem the web config file should be configured in the following way:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
</appSettings>
```

Is there any way to change the web.config file of an Azure Function App? Where I will find it? Or should I create it by myself? Do you have any other ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it with the properties of "maxOutstandingRequests" and "maxConcurrentRequests" in the host.json in your azure function(go to your function app --> Overview --> Function app settings --> host.json), please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings)

Hope it would be helpful to your problem.